# gcc warning -Wsign-compare doesn't seem to work when comparing const

Tags: c++, gcc

I seem to not be getting sign compare errors on my g++ gcc version 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4) (GCC).

When I compile the following with the options I don't get an error - but when I get rid of the const - it shows the warning.

Question: Is this expected behavior?

```
g++ typecompat.cxx -Wsign-compare -std=c++14
```

This is the code

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

 int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {1,2,3};
    const int b = 2;
    assert(v.size()>b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possibly because it is const, it knows that the value is in range of both signed and unsigned and therefore there can't be a problem.  If it is non-const, the value might change, and the comparison could lead to trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [godbolt session of this code](http://goo.gl/L3OAc4) it looks like gcc is performing constant folding:

```
cmpq    $2, %rax
```

So then it knows for sure the comparison is ok, any attempting to change a constant variable is undefined behavior and the compiler will assume no undefined behavior. If we look at the [documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) it does say:

> Warn when a comparison between signed and unsigned values **could produce an incorrect result** when the signed value is converted to unsigned

This  gcc bug report [Bogus warning with -Wsign-compare](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11492) looks like it covers this kind of false positive detection:

> To be useful, these warnings are meant to be smart - not warning if it can
>   be proved that the signed value is nonnegative [...]